# download a pdf from a website and change title - python and curl

Tags: python, html, pdf

I have a python script to download pdf's from a ASP-site. I would like to save the pdf file using the name it is displayed on the website. So from this line of html, get the link to download the pdf and get the name how it is displayed. So for the following html line:

```
<a href="https://www.ib3.nl/curriculum/engels\100 TB 3 Ch 3.pdf">Chapter 3 - Weird science</a></li>
```

get the link `https://www.ib3.nl/curriculum/engels\100 TB 3 Ch 3.pdf`
and save this pdf as `Chapter 3 - Weird science.pdf`

below is the script to get all the pdf's

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as requests
from urllib import parse as urlparse
import requests
import os


klassen = ['1e klas']
vakken = ['Wiskunde']
'''['Engels','Aardrijkskunde','Economie', 'Filosofie','Frans', 'Geschiedenis', \
          'Nask', 'Natuurkunde', 'Nederlands', 'Scheikunde', 'Spaans', 'Wiskunde'\
          'Biologie', 'Duits', 'Grieks','Latijn','Leesmateriaal', \
          'Loopbaanorientatie','NLT']'''
links = []
for klas in klassen: 
    for vak in vakken: 
        url = "https://www.svpo.nl/curriculum.asp"
        payload = 'vak='+ vak + '&klas_en_schoolsoort='+klas
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
        }

    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    
    path_out = 'c:\books\\'
    path = (path_out + klas + "\\" + vak + "\\")
    if not(os.path.exists(path)): os.makedirs(path)
    
    links = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")#.find_all('a')
    a=BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml").find_all('a')
    
    for link in BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml").find_all('a'):
        current_link = link.get('href')
        if str(link.get('href')) != 'None':
            if current_link.endswith('pdf'):
                print(current_link)
                links.append(current_link)
                filename = current_link[current_link.find('\\')+1:]
                filename_url = urlparse.quote(filename) 
                path_url = current_link[:current_link.find('\\')] + '/' + filename_url
                os.system('Curl -o "' + path + filename + '" ' + path_url)
```

Comment: to donwnload file you could use `requests` instead of `os.system(`curl`)`

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. If you have `<a>` in variable `link` then you need `link.text` (or `link.string`) or safer `link.get_text()`

Comment: it is simpler to use dictionary - `payload = {'vak': vak, 'klas_en_schoolsoort': klas}` - and `requests` will automatically convert it to string with `=` and &`

Comment: simpler `path = os.path.join(path_out, klas, vak)`

Comment: BTW: as I remeber `\b` may have special meaning in string - probably `backspace` - so better use \\ in `c:\\books` or use prefix `r` (for `raw string`) `r'c:\books'`

Comment: shorter `os.makedirs(path, exists_ok=True)` without `if not os.path.exists(path):` and it will create folder only if it doesn't exist (without raising error).

Comment: you can use `find_all('a', {'href': True})` and later you don't have to check `if str(link.get('href')) != 'None':`. Beside you could check `if link.get('href') is not None`  without `str()` and withou `' '`, or even shorter `if link.get('href'):`

Comment: simpler `filename = url.split('\\')[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
filename = link.text + '.pdf'
```

That's all.

---

My version with changes from comments:

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import parse as urlparse


klassen = ['1e klas']
vakken = ['Wiskunde']
'''['Engels','Aardrijkskunde','Economie', 'Filosofie','Frans', 'Geschiedenis', \
          'Nask', 'Natuurkunde', 'Nederlands', 'Scheikunde', 'Spaans', 'Wiskunde'\
          'Biologie', 'Duits', 'Grieks','Latijn','Leesmateriaal', \
          'Loopbaanorientatie','NLT']'''

links = []

url = "https://www.svpo.nl/curriculum.asp"
headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

path_out = r'c:\books'

for klas in klassen: 
    for vak in vakken: 
        path = os.path.join(path_out, klas, vak)
        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

        payload = {'vak': vak, 'klas_en_schoolsoort': klas}
        
        response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    
        all_links = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml").find_all('a', {'href': True})
    
        for link in all_links:
            url = link.get('href')

            if url.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
                url = url.replace('\\', '/')
                links.append(url)
                print('url:', url)
                
                #filename = url.split('\\')[-1]
                filename = link.text + '.pdf'
                print('filename:', filename)
                
                full_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
                print('full_path:', full_path)
                
                response = requests.get(url)
                with open(full_path, 'wb') as fh:
                    fh.write(response.content)
                    
                print('---')
```